# Mocking AngularJS controller ends with TypeError

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, mocking, resharper, jasmine

I'm trying to run Angular's PhoneCat tutorial in Visual Studio as a web page project. I've gotten to step 2 (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) and the web page is working fine. However, the unit test fails on the beforeEach line with the error:

> TypeError: Unable to get property '$injector' of undefined or null reference
>
> > at workFn(...scripts\angular-mocks.js:2013:7)

I have a test without any mocking, so I know that all the other components are playing nicely together. Basically, Visual Studio 2013, ReSharper 8, and Jasmine 2 all appear to be working nicely. Outside of unit tests, the page itself works fine. It comes up and shows the three phones defined in the controller.

I'm not strong enough (yet) in javascript to dig in and figure it out, so I'm coming here to ask for some help. You can see all the code on my github at https://github.com/qanwi1970/PhoneCat-VS/tree/develop. If my group goes forward with Angular, then being able to write meaningful unit tests in Visual Studio is very important.

Thanks for your help and tips.

UPDATE: I have discovered that the /// comments at the top of the js file tell Visual Studio of the required javascript files (for Intellisense and such) but it does not tell the test runners. I need to leave for the day, but that's the angle I'll be working tomorrow. How do I tell ReSharper/Chutzpah controllerSpec.js needs controller.js? This question is probably already answered, but I'm out of time for the day.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: @Rogier21 Not yet. I did try running the tests with Chutzpah instead of ReSharper and I get a different error, but it's in the same line of code. It says. "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Module in ... controllersspec.js:18"

Comment: Shame, I have the exact same problem, but even 8.2.1 didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using ReSharper 8.2.1. There were some fixes there for Jasmine 2.0 support that could result in an error similar to this.

Comment: It appears that my license, which was fine for 8.2.0, does not cover 8.2.1. If this is the fix, then I will have to look for a non-ReSharper way to run my Angular tests.

Comment: You don't need a new license for 8.2.1 - it's a minor maintenance release. Your 8.x license should work fine. If it's not accepted, you should contact support@jetbrains.com, because something's gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Update from 8.2.0 to 8.2.3 fixed this for me.